# Google Map + JS (add circle)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geometry

I want to draw circle on google maps using JS.

My code:

Button code:

INDEX.HTML

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="test1" onclick="DrawCircle()">Wyświetlk mapę
```

Div for map (index.html):

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;">
    <script>mapping()</script>
</div>
```

Function for draw map and one sample circle  (functions.js)

```
function mapping(){

    var citymap = 
    {
          warsaw: 
          {
            center: {lat: 52.14, lng: 21.1},  
            population: 1740000
          }
    }


    function initialize() {
      var mapProp = {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(52.13 ,19.02),
        zoom:6,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    for (var city in citymap) 
    {

        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          center: citymap[city].center,
          radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 30
    });
    }

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
```

And function to draw circle:

```
function DrawCircle()
    {

        draw_circle = new.google.maps.Circle({

            center: {lat: 52.94, lng: 20.1},
            radius: 2000,
            strokeColor: "#000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.6,
            strokeWeight: 2;
            fillColor: "#0099AA",
            fillOpacity: 0.25,
            map: map
        });

    }
```

I have an error : 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
(index):198 Uncaught ReferenceError: mapping is not defined

What change/add (repiar)?
I cant find solve to this problem here and on the google api documentation.

I will be glad for help

Comment: You have two typos in your code: 1. `new.google.maps.Circle({` (should be a space between new and google) 2. `strokeWeight: 2;` (should be a comma).  [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zcuo7o5w/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `mapping()` probably before it is defined.

Where is your JavaScript code located in your HTML page?

Make sure the JavaScript block you posted is located in your HTML *before* your call to `mapping()`.

However I would assume that `mapping()` as a function is not very useful anyway because you are already using a `load` listener which calls `initialize`.

So I would suggest removing this `<script>mapping()</script>` altogether and also removing the `function mapping() { ... }` around your code, and it should work automagically regardless of where you put the code. Just make sure to call `DrawCircle` only after the initialization code ran. You may put it into the `initialize` function itself, for example.

(And by the way, I'm not sure if the line `draw_circle = ...` does what you want. I would assume you at least need a `var` before it to prevent accidentally creating a global variable.)

Also I would suggest indenting your code properly, it is very unclear where the different function scopes are.

**EDIT**: I noticed another issue: `new.google.maps.circle` is not valid code (`new` is a keyword). I guess you want `new google.maps.circle` without the first dot? If this syntax error would cause your whole external JavaScript file not to be loaded (especially since you have, as you explained in the comments, included it in the `<head>` area), it would also explain why `mapping` can't be found.

You should fix this error and you should also make sure you have the developer console open (press F12 in your browser) while loading the page, and look into the console tab there, since you would have seen the syntax error reported there (probably with a link to where exactly in the file the error happened).

Comment: If i delete the script mapping(), map will be not show (javascript code is on the other file)

Comment: 1) Did you also, as I suggested, remove the `function mapping() { ... }` wrapper around the main code? 2) Yes but where is the other file included?

Comment: i have index.html where is only div and in head url to function.js.
In function JS i have this script.

Comment: OK I think the issue is a different one then. I found an extra syntax error in your code which I missed at first. It would explain why it doesn't work - because your whole JS file isn't loaded due to the syntax error! Please read my EDIT I added to the answer.